# change string to different string

Tags: javascript, string

```
function User(number){
    let string = "";
   
 
    for(i=number; i>0; i--){
      for(j=0; j<i; j++){
      string = string  + i

    }
    string = string +"\n"
    }
    return string
  }
    
  User(5)
  console.log(User(5))
```

I have

```
55555
4444
333
22
1
```

I want to make

```
XXXXX
XXXX
XXX
XX
X
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right code? Does not seem an attempt to do what you want to achieve.

Comment: @TusharShahi of course I'm also confused what he want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concat the value of `i` you can concat `x`

```js
function User(number) {
  let string = "";

  for (let i = number; i > 0; i--) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      string = string + 'x';

    }
    string = string + "\n"
  }
  return string
}

console.log(User(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?
Concating integer `i` instead of `X`

```js
function User(number){
    let string = "";
   
 
    for(i=number; i>0; i--){
      for(j=0; j<i; j++){
      string = string  + "X"

    }
    string = string +"\n"
    }
    return string
  }
  console.log(User(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
string = string  + i;
```

To :

```
string = string  + 'X';
```